# Language Change is not able to apply to Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, locale

I would like to change system language to Japanese.
However, the change is not apply.
I have installed Arch Linux on ThinkPad X13 AMD (Ryzen7 4750U).

I have set up Gnome then I tried change system language from Gnome Settings GUI(regions/language), But change setting is not apply.

Also I tried change locale LANG setting with setting files and command like [Arch wiki locale page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#Setting_the_locale), (`locale-gen`(commented out en_US.UTF-8 and ja_JP.UTF-8, then edit `/etc/locale.conf` and `localectl set-locale`), it does not applied.

BTW, I have other errors like following picture.
It causes when boot time, so login screen does not appear (it need put Ctrl-Alt-F1 then Ctrl-Alt-F2 to appear login screen)
[image]

I have no idea whether these errors are related to Language change problem.

How do I make change language in gnome on Arch Linux?

locale -a:

My environment:

- Linux Kernel 5.7.5
- Arch Linux
- Gnome 3.36

Comment: it's not clear - did you do 1) editing /etc/locale.gen with sudo rights, 2) sudo locale-gen, 3) logout, login ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has solved.
I did reinstall gnome then problem has solved.
I have no idea what was wrong eventually.